# Adding new attribute in an existing element node

Tags: marklogic

I need syntax to add new attribute in an existing element node.
Sample

```
<version id="1" version-status="active">
<source/>
<file-text>ABC</file-text>
.
.
.
<file-date>07/06/2017</file-date>
</version>
```

I want to add new attribute(myAttribute) to version element by keeping rest of the data inside version as it is.
eg.

```
<version id="1" status="active" myAttribute="true">
<source/>
<file-text>ABC</file-text>
.
.
.
<file-date>07/06/2017</file-date>
</version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xdmp:node-insert-child()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-insert-child), that also works on attributes:

```
xdmp:document-insert("/test.xml", <version id="1" version-status="active">
  <source/>
  <file-text>ABC</file-text>
  ...
  <file-date>07/06/2017</file-date>
</version>)

;

xdmp:node-insert-child(doc("/test.xml")/version, attribute myAttribute { "true" })

;

doc("/test.xml")
```

HTH!